# How do I get the current page's URL in an Android WebView using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, url, android-webview

I'm using a `WebView` to scrape an unholy mess of a website with a bizarre mix of HTTP and Javascript redirects. In my injected script, I need to get the current URL, but it seems like none of the relevant properties ever return anything other than the URL I passed to `WebView.loadUrl`, even after a redirect.

I've tried:

- `window.location`
- `window.location.href`
- `document.URL`
- `document.location`
- `document.location.href`
- `document.documentURI`

So what's going on here and how am I supposed to get the current page's URL with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was injecting my script in the `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` method to try and make it execute as soon as possible, but it appears that the window context isn't completely set up at that point. When I moved my injection code to `WebViewClient.onPageFinished`, it started retrieving an accurate URL from the properties I listed. It's not really an ideal solution, since my script now has to wait for the entire page to load, but I don't know of any other way to do it.